# How would one give a probability measure for a set of numbers

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have the following set of numbers:

```
  63    60    58    60    60    60    58    62    62    60    61
```

I need some way to give these numbers a probability measure. These numbers correspond to  costs of choosing different options for a stochastic hill climbing algorithm. For example `63` is a cost if I choose option **A** for the algorithm, `60` is a cost I get, if I choose option **B** and so on.

I need to add a probability for each selection. The better the cost (i.e. lower) is the higher the probability should be for selecting that particular option.

How would one determine a probability for these selections?...The numbers correspond to the number of simple actions a machine needs to do in order to get a job done.

Another note: Is this a question of computer science or mathematics? I'm not sure so I posted it here =)

Here is some reference (short):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_hill_climbing

Thank you for any suggestions =)

Comment: then choose option C or option G (both with cost 58) with probability 1. I assume there is something I am missing

Comment: Thank you for your help @Stefanos, but wouldn't that be a greedy version of Hill climbing? Because the best choices are selected always? =) I'm trying to do Stochastic hill climbing in order to avoid local minimums. The point is that I have a set of options, with probability of selection varying on HOW GOOD the selection is. Selection 63 might have e.g. a selection probability of 20 %, whereas 58 could have 30 % chance etc. The better the cost the higher the probability of selection. The idea in stochastic hill climbing is not to choose the best always, but with SOME probability =)

Comment: I need a way to give these numbers a probability, which will sum up to one =) See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_hill_climbing

Comment: Presumably the sum of the probabilities across all 11 (always 11?) options needs to sum to 1 - yes? You also want the probabilities to be a decreasing function of the score. It's now down to what shape of function you want - linear, decreasing gradient (gets steeper with increasing score), etc. Answers to this latter may be related to objectives for your algorithm - speed, how often it gets caught on local optima, etc. If you don't know (or are experimenting) then start simple and go for a simple linear function.

Comment: The easiest way is to do a weighted average. That is, if option $x$ has cost $C(x)$, then the probability that it will be chosen is $$1 - \frac{C(x)}{C_{\text{tot}},$$ where $C_{\text{tot}}$ is the sum of all costs.

Comment: +1 @DMM Thank you for your help :) No there doesn't have to be always 11 options, it can vary on the amount of options. Yes that is correct, a decreasing function of the score, the higher the score/cost the lower the probability, better options are given higher probability.

Comment: +1 @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for your help =) Can you edit the LaTex a bit? ;)

Comment: +1 @DMM about the shape of the function: Short answer: I don't know...I need to try, which one gives me the best results :)

Comment: I forgot to normalize; the correct probability should be $$P(x)=\frac{1}{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{C(x)}{C_{\text{tot}}} \right), $$
where $n$ is the number of options.

Comment: +1 @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for your help! Appreciate! =)

Comment: @DMM the probabilities should sum up to one yes =)

Comment: @GuiseppeNego This is a valid solution but, in this case, does not provide much discrimination between the different options (see my more general linear solution). Whether the degree of discrimination between different options is important in the context of the algorithm is a matter for jjepsuomi .

Comment: @jjepsuomi Ok, thanks for the explanation, I was indeed missing the main idea of stochastic hill climbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using a linear function $P(x) = a + bC(x)$ where $C(x)$ is the cost of option $x$.

The constraints are $\sum {P(x)} = 1$, $ 0 \le P(x) \le 1$ and $b \lt 0 $. The latter constraint provides the requirement that $P(x)$ should decrease as $C(x)$ increases.

The sum constraint implies $ na + bC_\text{tot} = 1 $ where $C_\text{tot}$ is the total of all costs and $n$ is the number of options. This yields $a$ as $$a = \frac{1-bC_\text{tot}}n = 1/n - bC_\text{ave}$$ and $P(x)$ may be re-written solely in terms of $b$ as$$P(x) = 1/n +b(C(x) - C_\text{ave})$$

Because $b<0$, $P(x)$ has a maximum at $C_\text{min}$, the minimum of the $C(x)$ values, and a minimum at $C_\text{max}$, the corresponding maximum. The constraints $ 0 \le P(x) \le 1$ on $P(x)$ imply that
$$0 \le 1/n + b(C_\text{max}-C_\text{ave})$$ and $$1 \ge 1/n + b(C_\text{min}-C_\text{ave})$$ The first of these yields $$b \ge \frac{-1}{n(C_\text{max}-C_\text{ave})}$$whilst the second yields $$ b \ge \frac{n}{(n-1)(C_\text{min}-C_\text{ave})}$$ Note that the RHS of the inequality is negative in both cases and because both must be satisfied, the effective lower bound for $b$ will be the greater of the two RHS values (by design $b$ has an upper bound of zero). This is a general solution and the "weighted average" solution provided in an earlier comment corresponds to a value of $b$ given by $-1/[C_\text{tot}(n-1)]$.

The value of $b$ affects the solution quite dramatically. For the data set provided $b$ has a lower bound of $\frac{-1}{29}$ and, at this bound, the probabilities range from $0$ at the maximum score of $63$ to a maximum of $\sim 0.1724$ at the minimum score of $58$. In contrast the "weighted average" solution corresponds to a larger value of $b$ and the probabilities fall within a much narrower range - $\sim 0.0905$ to $\sim 0.0912$. Thus, $b$ can be used to tune the probability values in a way affects the degree of discrimination available between the options and, as a result, different values of $b$ will possibly provide differing levels of performance for the algorithm in which the probabilities are used.

Comment: +1 Thank you @DMM excellent! =) Appreciate your effort! Hope this will help others in similar problems as well =)